# How to perform validation in spring mvc without using annotations

Tags: spring

```
 @RequestMapping("/validateMsg")
     public boolean validateEmp(@ModelAttribute Employee emp,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model){
         boolean iserror=false;
                 if(emp.getFirstName()=="")
                 {
                     model.addAttribute("firstName","firstName is required");
                     iserror=true;
                 }
         return iserror;
}
```

I have written this code is this correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use a validator.

```
@Component
public class EmploeeValidator implements Validator{
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Emploee.class.equals(clazz);
    }
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "someProp", "someProp.empty");
        //other valdiation...
    }
}
```

Then in the controller

```
    @Autowired
    private EmploeeValidator validator;
    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }
```

Use it:

```
 @RequestMapping("/emploee")
 public boolean addEmp(@Valid Employee emp,Errors errors){
         if(errors.hasErrors()){
            //it's not valid
         } else {
            //ok
         }
 }
```